# python requests module doesnt work when curl works. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a curl request and a similar request using python requests module to a local web service. While the curl request is working correctly, the request made via python isnt working as expected, ie doesn't return a json reponse.

Any ideas as why this is happening? With python I still get a 200 response, but getting HTML response text instead of json like in curl and the response is something about invalid session etc.

This is the curl request

```
root@weve1:~$ curl -k --GET --data "ajax=getPermissions&project=test&session.id=5604d7ce-f3dd-4349-8957-563c2675ae5c" http://localhost:12320/manager
{
  "permissions" : [ {
    "permission" : [ "ADMIN" ],
    "username" : "azkaban"
  } ],
  "project" : "test",
  "projectId" : 92
}
```

This is the same request made in python

```
root@weve1:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> s=requests.get('http://localhost:12320/manager',data={'ajax':'getPermissions','project':'test','session.id':'5604d7ce-f3dd-4349-8957-563c2675ae5c'})
>>> s.json()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 741, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
>>>
```

Comment: Maybe look at the text response first before you try to convert it from JSON?

Comment: I looked at the response.text and it's html blob and not json. I'm guessing the service returns html instead of json when the data sent to it is not in the right format. I'm just wondering what might be wrong

Comment: @poke .. no it's not a POST. when I do curl -x -POST, it doesnt get any data  back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the curl man page:

> `-G/--get`
>
> When used, this option will make all data specified with -d/--data or --data-binary to be used in a HTTP GET request instead of the POST request that otherwise would be used. The data will be appended to the URL with a '?' separator.

So curl is actually passing the parameters as a query string instead, i.e. `http://localhost:12320/manager?ajax=getPermissions&project=test&session.id=5604d7ce-f3dd-4349-8957-563c2675ae5c`.

In order to pass data in the URL with requests, you need to pass the data [in the `params` argument](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls):

```
data = { 'ajax': 'getPermissions', 'project': 'test', 'session.id': '5604d7ce-f3dd-4349-8957-563c2675ae5c' }
s = requests.get('http://localhost:12320/manager', params=data)
```

The `data` argument only refers to the actual request body.