# curl works but not python requests.get()

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I've found some similar questions on stackoverflow ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164869/curl-works-but-python-requests-doesnt),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298936/python-requests-library-is-not-working-while-curl-is-working),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125537/python-requests-module-doesnt-work-when-curl-works-what-am-i-doing-wrong)), but none of them solved my problem.

The URL is something like "https://example.com/api.php?foo=bar".
Using the following command will get a json string:

```sh
curl "https://example.com/api.php?foo=bar"
```

while using the following code returns a 502 response (bad gate way):

```py
import requests
requests.get("https://example.com/api.php?foo=bar")
```

Currently I'm using the following code as a workaround, but I'd like to know why requests.get() doesn't work.

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['curl','-s','https://example.com/api.php?foo=bar'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the parameter `foo` with the value `bar` using the `params` keyword instead of as part of the URL:

```
payload = {"foo": "bar"}
requests.get("https://www.example.com/api.php", params=payload)
```

[documentation page](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: What do you mean? That's not an exception. requests.get() returns a Response with status=502 @lora

Comment: It's not an exception, but running a debugger might get you more information. Without an actual URL or a more explicit 502 error it's hard to say why this is happening. You could try passing a user agent header.